# Vim very annoying and slow behavior with ConEmu

Tags: windows, vim, conemu

This GIF image illustrates my problem:

[image]

My execution environment:

- Windows 7 SP1
- Vim74 (Windows version)
- ConEmu latest version x64 version

My `.vimrc`  file: [529-line file on codepad](http://codepad.org/dI1vUOqy)

Settings related to my problem (as I think):

- `set term=xterm`
- `set t_Co=256`
- `let &t_AB="\e[48;5;%dm"`
- `let &t_AF="\e[38;5;%dm"`

My problem:

1. When I scroll down, texts are rendered very slowly.
2. Annoying cursor(?) appears randomly on screen.
3. I have this problem even with plain text files.
4. Very short (less than 50 lines but with scrollable line long) files.

Solutions I tried:

- Reduce synmaxcolum by `set synmaxolum=50`
- Remove line `set=xterm` (this solves the problem but I need 256 colors)
- I tested on Ubuntu and Cygwin with same `.vimrc` file and plugins but there was no problem at all  :-0
- GVim works fine

Comment: There is something wrong with formatting. Please edit your post.

Comment: Your gif doesn't show full window.

Comment: Which vim are you using? It is possible to run vim inside Conemu in multiple ways: embed graphical VIM window, launch `cmd` and run text mode vim, or run vim inside MinGW or other unix like environment. Judging from `term` variable, it doesn't look like graphical VIM.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @SimonHartcher No

Comment: @이햇살 Using gvim fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `xterm` gives you 8 colors, not 256. You need `xterm-256color` for that.
2. If your `$TERM` is `xterm-256color` (or some similar value) you don't need to lie to Vim with `set t_Co=256`.